# NServiceBus.Host - How do I add the endpoint instance to my IoC container

Tags: nservicebus

I'm trying to upgrade a solution from NServiceBus 5 to 6.  Currently, we are injecting IBus to a service class so that the service can send messages to the bus as needed.  Now that IBus is no longer available in 6, how do I inject the endpoint instance when the endpoint is created using NServiceBus.Host, which will itself start this endpoint?

There is an example provided at the bottom of https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/multi-hosting/:

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Samples.MultiHosting.Instance1");
endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
return Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration);
```

However, it is immediately followed by a note indicating "*this is possible only when self-hosting and not using NServiceBus.Host*."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `IWantToRunWhenEndpointStartsAndStops` implementation to inject the `IMessageSession` for your service class after the bus has started.

Here is the relevant section from the Upgrade Guide for NServiceBus.Host:
https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/host-6to7#iwanttorunwhenendpointstartsandstops-interface-in-version-7-of-nservicebus-host

An alternative would be to switch to the [NServiceBus Windows Service Bootstrap](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Bootstrap.WindowsService) instead of using NServiceBus.Host where you will have more control over the endpoint's lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I neglected to include in my original post that I did look into seeing if I could get the endpoint that was started within IWantToRunWhenEndpointStartsAndStops.Start().  However, I'm not seeing a way to do this.

Comment: The `IMessageSession` passed in the Start method is the endpoint and will give you access to `Send` and `Publish`.

Comment: I had to rework my service class to account for the possibility that an `IEndpointInstance` or `IMessageSession` is injected, but everything appears to be working as expected. Thanks!