# Cannot resolve IMessageSession with CastleWindsor in NServiceBus - 6.x

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus v6, with NServiceBus.Host.  I am not able to resolve the messageSession object.  What am I missing?

```
var container2 = new WindsorContainer();
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("logging.config"));
        LogManager.Use<Log4NetFactory>();

        endpointConfiguration.DefineEndpointName("Strategy.Service");
        endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>();
        endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>();
        endpointConfiguration.Conventions()
            .DefiningCommandsAs(x => x.Namespace != null && x.Namespace.Contains("Commands"))
            .DefiningEventsAs(x => x.Namespace != null && x.Namespace.Contains("Events"));
        endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<WindsorBuilder>(
            customizations: customizations =>
            {
                customizations.ExistingContainer(container2);
            });
        endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
        endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
        endpointConfiguration.DefineCriticalErrorAction(onCriticalError: async context =>
        {
            _logger.Fatal($"CRITICAL: {context.Error}", context.Exception);
            await context.Stop()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var output =
                $"NServiceBus critical error: {Environment.NewLine}{context.Error}{Environment.NewLine}Shutting Down.";
            Environment.FailFast(output, context.Exception);
        });
        var msgSessions = container2.Resolve<IMessageSession>(); // Cannot resolve IMessageSession.
```

Answer (score 4):

`IMessageSession` is not registered in the container by NServiceBus. You will get a reference to the `IMessageSession` when you start the endpoint:

```
var endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration);
IMessageSession messageSession = endpointInstance as IMessageSession;
```

See https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/5to6/moving-away-from-ibus#dependency-injection for more information about why `IMessageSession` is not injected into the container by NServiceBus.

Comment: I am using NServiceBus.Host - So I get the EndPointConfiguration Instance and I dont have to worry about Starting the endpoint.  I have a crude way of implementing IWantToRunWhenEndpointStartsAndStops to get an instance of IMessageSession - But I am not sure if thats the right approach

Comment: This answer I gave to another question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40348435/1322687