# How to configure NServiceBus 6 to use an existing StructureMap container in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, nservicebus, structuremap

I have a Web API application working with StructureMap and I've introduced the latest version of NServiceBus (version 6) to introduce pub/sub for changed data.

The problem is I don't seem to be able to get the existing container to inject to the StructureMapBuilder.

The structure is as follows:

```
public class WebApiRegistry : Registry
{
    public WebApiRegistry()
    {
        For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));
        For(typeof(IProcessor<>)).Use(typeof(PassThroughProcessor<>));
        For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<UnitOfWork>();
        For<ILog>().Use(container => LogManager.GetLogger("My.WebApi"));
    }
}
```

This registry is then registered in the Aplication_Start method in the Global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStructureMap<WebApiRegistry>();
```

The problem is here, in the same method:

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("My.WebApi.Sender");
endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<NServiceBus.JsonSerializer>();
endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<StructureMapBuilder>(); //No idea how to get the existing container in here???
endpointConfiguration.SendOnly();
```

I cannot figure out how to register the existing container with NServiceBus.

I've got an example working with AutoFac which is probably because it's the default DI framework of choice for NServiceBus, but I'm keen to get it working with StructureMap.

Any ideas?

Comment: This should work. https://docs.particular.net/samples/containers/structuremap/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately that doesn't work: 'No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'NServiceBus.IMessageSession' is the result when I invoke the controller action that is configured to send. Also, having to repeat the WebApiRegistry code in the Global.asax is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Check answer provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the container manually and use it for both Web API and NServiceBus

```
var registry = new WebApiRegistry();
var container = new Container(registry);

//Register StructureMap with GlobalConfiguration
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStructureMap(container);


var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("My.WebApi.Sender");

//...other code removed for brevity

//Configuring NServiceBus to use the container
endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<StructureMapBuilder>(
    customizations: customizations => {
        customizations.ExistingContainer(container);
    });

//...other code removed for brevity

var endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration); 
// OR Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
IMessageSession messageSession = endpointInstance as IMessageSession;

// Now, change the container configuration to know how to resolve IMessageSession
container.Configure(x => x.For<IMessageSession>().Use(messageSession));
```

Comment: @BillyRayValentine take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40622554/5233410  and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348435/5233410

Comment: @BillyRayValentine looks like `NServiceBus.IMessageSession` is not registered with the container by default and is only available after you start the endpoint. so need to find a way to get it into the container

Comment: @BillyRayValentine I think I figured it out. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it's working, but now I'm getting a weird queue error: "The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation" I reckon I'll have to post another question later.